# Passing variables to jQuery from links

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am remaking a page on the admin section of a website I administer so that it uses jQuery and AJAX. On one of the pages I have a list of items. Next to each item there is a link which is something like this:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=48" class="del_link">delete</a>
```

If I give these links a class I can easily apply a jQuery function to all of them but they would all call the same function in the same way. My question is: what is the best way for the function to get the item's id without including JavaScript inline with the html?

Update: 
Thanks for the pointers, everyone.
I've ended up using this:

```
$(".del_link").click(function(){
    var del_link = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#results").load(del_link, function (){
        $("#results").show().delay().fadeTo(2000, 0);
    })
})
```

The php file that the ajax calls responds in different ways if it's been requested by ajax or normally - if it's ajax it outputs a response (e.g. "Item was deleted successfully") which can be displayed in the #results div. If someone has javascript disabled the client will be directed to the same php page but it will redirect them once the item is removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
$('.del_link').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('href').split('=')[1];
    // Do something with the ID here
});
```

**Be warned**, this won't work if the link URL has more than one querystring parameter. In that scenario you'd have to do some slightly more complicated parsing of the `attr('href')` value.

Answer (score 2):

well, you can get the href easily enough:

```
var id = $('.del_link a').attr('href');
```

then just parse the id out.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML 5 you can use data attributes. Something like

```
<a href="delete.php?id=48" class="del_link" data-id='48'>delete</a>
```

and jQuery

```
$("a.del_link").each(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

Read [**this**](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) article on HTML 5 data attributes

Answer (score 0):

When you add an `onClick` handler then `this` will be the link.

Examine the `href` attribute (use `this.href`) and parse the ID.